# Error Use of undefined constant usando compact()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, aplicación-web

tengo un problema en laravel 5.5 que es esto:

> ErrorException (E_WARNING)
>   Use of undefined constant datosalumno - assumed 'datosalumno' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

En esta linea de código donde me muestra el error la cual esta en mi controlador DatosAlumnoController.php:

```
    public function edit($id)
{
    $datosalumno = DatosAlumno::find($id);
   return view('datosalumno.edit',compact(datosalumno));
}
```

Comment: No sería más lógico añadir el $ en el compact? La variable como tal la tiene definida anteriormente... Algo como `compact($datodalumno)`

Comment: Según tengo entendido está bien el formato, incluso agregué lo que mencionas y me sigue dando el mismo error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Aunque todos tenemos muy claro que esto no es más que un error tipográfco, decidí redactar esta respuesta porque considero que el OP no tiene muy claro cómo usar `compact()`.**

Antes que nada, `compact()` es una función de PHP, no de Laravel (aunque se recomienda su utilización con dicho framework).

Entonces, como es una función PHP, podemos revisar su documentación en https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.compact.php

> compact — Crear un array que contiene variables y sus valores

Los parámetros que recibe son según su documentación:

> compact() toma un número variable de parámetros. Cada parámetro puede ser una cadena que contiene el nombre de la variable, o un array de nombres de variables. El array puede contener otros arrays de nombres de variables dentro de él; compact() los trata recursivamente.

Teniendo en cuenta la documentación, lo que se suele hacer en Laravel es **pasar cadenas que contienen el nombre de la variable**, por ejemplo si tengo una variable `$usuario`, entonces la cadena que debería pasar es `'usuario'`.

Lo que estás haciendo actualmente es pasar el nombre de una constante (inexistente), las cuales se definen sin el símbolo de dólar ($) al inicio, y tampoco están encerradas en comillas simples o dobles.

En ese orden de ideas, lo que creo que intentas hacer es pasar la cadena con el nombre de la variable, entonces debes usar comillas simples (idealmente):

```
return view('datosalumno.edit', compact('datosalumno'));
```

Comment: Pues yo también desconocía el uso de compact. Gracias, algo nuevo que se aprende.